# Screen sharing - can you prevent the attached screen from turning on?

Tags: screen-sharing

I have a machine at work that I sometimes like to connect to using screen sharing, but I don't want anyone else in the office to be able to see what I'm doing.  I also don't want to give them access to the computer - I password-lock my screen with a screen saver when I'm not at the machine, but when I log on with screen sharing, I have to disable this lock.

So, is there any way to prevent the original screens from becoming active while using screen sharing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Lion this is possible, but don't remember seeing this anywhere in previous versions. When you start a screen sharing session it will ask you how you want to view the remote session.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that tip - I'll look next time I log in to see if I can find the settings that control that.

Comment: I just connected, and screen sharing did not ask me how I wanted to view the remote screen.  There are options for 'observe' and 'control' in preferences, but I want to control *without* activating the remote screen.

Comment: I have added the option i get given when i try to screen share. This has worked on when both computers are running Lion.